# Store hex value in string C++

Tags: c++, hex

For example :

```
char str[] = {0x1B, 0x54, 0x32, 0xFE, 0x88, 0x10, 0x34, 0x6F, 0x54};
```

But this is C style. So how can i do same with `std::string` and without using C functions?

Comment: Do you need a character string, or a char buffer?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. String suggests that it's some text which it isn't in your case. An array of integers is better, `int8_t` if you really want small ones only and are concerned about space.

Comment: This will work in both C and C++: `"\x1B\x54\x32\xFE\x88\x10\x34\x6F\x54"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So how can i do same with std::string and without using C functions?

try this:

```
std::string str{0x1B, 0x54, 0x32, 0xFE, 0x88, 0x10, 0x34, 0x6F, 0x54};
```

or this:

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

auto str = "\x1B5432FE8810346F54"s;
```

or this:

```
std::string str = "\x1B5432FE8810346F54";
```

Comment: Thanks. And how i can add `\x1B5432FE8810346F54` to `vector<char>`?

Comment: @kimezehig, try `std::vector<char> v{0x1B, 0x54, 0x32, 0xFE, 0x88, 0x10, 0x34, 0x6F, 0x54};`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
std::string s = "\x1B\x54\x32\xFE\x88\x10\x34\x6F\x54";
```